# Laravel 5: Using a controller in a view composer - controller class not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I followed [these instructions](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views#view-composers) and created a view composer for my default layout.

My **DefaultComposer.php** is located under app/Http/ViewComposers, hence the namespace used below:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class DefaultComposer {

    public function compose(View $view) {

        $data['language'] = LanguageController::getDefaultLanguage();

        $view->with($data);
    }

}

?>
```

Now, when I load a page, I get the following error:

**Class 'App\Http\ViewComposers\LanguageController' not found**

This happens because the **LanguageController.php** is placed under app/Http/Controllers, which is a different namespace.

How can I use the `LanguageController` class in my `DefaultComposer`?

---

**Update:**

Using this declaration:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\LanguageController as LanguageController;
```

throws: **Class 'App\Http\Controllers\LanguageController' not found**. I'm confused.

Comment: Controllers aren't really meant to be used in this way. Laravel's config would be a better approach for this purpose. However, does `\App\Http\Controllers\LanguageController::getDefaultLanguage()` work? And does LanguageController definitely define the correct namespace of `App\Http\Controllers`?

Comment: Yeah, I actually managed to get it to work. Posting answer in a few minutes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. As the controllers in my application live in the global namespace, all I needed to do is add a backslash in front of the class name.

So instead of this:

```
$data['language'] = LanguageController::getDefaultLanguage();
```

I did this:

```
$data['language'] = \LanguageController::getDefaultLanguage();
```

Comment: Or since they're in the global namespace you could have also done `use LanguageController;`